# This while loop doesn't seem to loop - there is only math in the loop

Tags: java

I can not figure out why my loop won't continue.  Every time I run the program, it executes only one iteration of the loop.

I am implementing the algorithm based on mathematician Lewis Caroll where you remove the last digit from an input number and subtract it from the number formed by the remaining digits. For example, if I input the number 48070 the output is

```
48070
4807
```

and it stops there instead of continuing.

```
// The "Divisible_Dianik" class.
import java.awt.*;

public class Divisible_Dianik
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int userinput = 1;
        int lastint;
        int firstpart;
        int output = 1;

        while (output != 0)
        {
            userinput = In.getInt ();
            lastint = userinput % 10;
            firstpart = userinput / 10;
            output = firstpart - lastint;
            System.out.println (output);
            userinput = output;
        }

    } // main method
} // Divisible_Dianik class
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with print statements or a debugger?

Comment: thats what we use in school for the user to input an integer.

Comment: Then it's a `In.class` what you have isn't it? Or do you have an `In.java`? If so, paste code here

Comment: @Frakcool:  That class would literally do us no good.  If all it does is read input from the command line, its behavior is easy enough to replicate.

Comment: @Makoto yeah I already saw that and also your answer, I was editing to format code. My bad :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that `In.getInt()` is some kind of abstraction for getting terminal-based feedback from the user.  It's easily supplanted by this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
// in the loop
userinput = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

If this is the case, the reason you don't loop is due to this blocking for input every time.  What you want to do is move the request for input *outside* of the loop.

```
int lastint;
int firstpart;
int output = 1;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int userinput = scan.nextInt();
while (output != 0) {
    lastint = userinput % 10;
    firstpart = userinput / 10;
    output = firstpart - lastint;
    System.out.println(output);
    userinput = output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! it even works if I just move the In.getInt ouside the loop too : )

Comment: @jso, this happens quite often on SO.